# Sort array of objects based on string parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of objects:

```
   [
     {
       "id" : 1,
       "pricePerDay" : 50,
     }, 
     {
       "id" : 2,
       "pricePerDay" : 70   
     }
   ]
```

Based on the user input from a  i want to filter either ASC or DESC on the `pricePerday`. Obviously this would work with:

```
 this.products.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.pricePerDay) - parseFloat(a.pricePerDay));
```

**BUT** i have the variable `filterType` which now contains the string `'pricePerDay'`. How can I use this variable to search the array of objects to properties that have the same key and sort this array based on that key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: @Wyck no, because in that example you know the key of the object property, in my case I need to search for this key based on the user input, which is the `filterType` variable

Comment: Are you looking for computed property names ? this.products.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b[filterType]) - parseFloat(a[filterType]));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.products.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b[filterType]) - parseFloat(a[filterType]));
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can change filterType to field that you want and acs to false if you want desc order

```js
 const arr = [
     {
       "id" : 1,
       "pricePerDay" : 50,
           
     }, 
     {
       "id" : 2,
       "pricePerDay" : 70   
     }
   ]

 let filterType = 'pricePerDay'
 let asc = false

 const res = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (asc) {
    return parseFloat(a[filterType]) - parseFloat(b[filterType])
  } else {
    return parseFloat(b[filterType]) - parseFloat(a[filterType])
  }
 });
 console.log(res)
```